# Replacing backslash by another symbol in escape symbol

Tags: java

I have string `some_text\1\12\3`. Need to get string `some_text.1.12.3`, i. e. replace `\` by `.`. The problem is that Java interprets `\1` as one symbol (escape-symbol). And actually I need to replace part of escape-symbol.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like all you're missing is the knowledge of how to escape the backslash in a Java string literal - which is a matter of doubling the backslash:

```
String replaced = original.replace('\\', '.');
```

On the other hand, it's not clear where your text is coming from or going to anyway - the `\1` part would *only* be relevant if it's being processed as part of a text literal. If you're actually trying to create a string of `"some_text\1\12\3"` in Java source code to start with, you'd want:

```
String withBackslashes = "some_text\\1\\12\\3";
```

Note that the actual text of the string that `withBackslashes` refers to only has three backslashes, not six. It's only the *source code* that needs them doubling. At that point, the replacement code at the top would replace the backslashes with dots.

Answer (score 5):

This will do the job:

```
str = str.replace('\\', '.');
```